# make an array from custom object properties

Tags: arrays, string, dictionary, swift3, key

I have a custom class like:

```
 class Tender: NSObject {
     public var code = ""
     public var name = ""
 }
```

A method returns an array of Tender type. From this array, I want to prepare an array that contains only name.
Example,

```
 public func fetchTenderArray() -> [Tender] {
      var tenderArray = [Tender]()
      let tender1 = Tender()
      tender1.code = "t1"
      tender1.name = "tenderName1"
      let tender2 = Tender()
      tender2.code = "t2"
      tender2.name = "tenderName2"
      tenderArray.append(tender1)
      tenderArray.append(tender2)
      return tenderArray
 }
```

Now, I have a method that uses this tenderArray. I need to form an array with the names of [Tender].

```
 public func formTenderNamesArray() -> [String] {
      let tenderArray = fetchTenderArray()
      var tenderNames = [String]()
      for tender in tenderArray {
           tenderNames.append(tender.name)
      }
      return tenderNames    // returns ["tenderName1","tenderName2"]
 }
```

Is there a short and a best way to prepare that array of strings using swift3?

Comment: Ever thought of using a hashmap or dictionary for storing the code (=key) and name (=value)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using map functionality,

it should be something like this.

```
let tenderArray = fetchTenderArray()
let tenderNames = tenderArray.map {$0.name}
```

For more information please see this link.

https://useyourloaf.com/blog/swift-guide-to-map-filter-reduce/

Answer (score 0):

//Try this

```
public func formTenderNamesArray() -> [String] {
    let tenderArray = fetchTenderArray()
    var tenderNames = (tenderArray as! NSArray).value(forKey: "name") as! [String]
    return tenderNames
}
```